# Travelling to Métabief (France) through Geneva airport in Switzerland

Tags: visas, france, transit-visas, switzerland, malaysian-citizens

I am a Malaysian. 
I will be travelling to Métabief  in France in June 2019 for a week.

As I will land at Geneva airport in Switzerland, I am wodering whether I need any visa in Switzerland and to cross border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

France and Switzerland are both part of the [Schengen area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), so your visa requirements for a short visit are those set out in the [Schengen visa policy](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en). There you can find a link to a document setting out lists of countries whose citizens do and do not need visas for short visits to the Schengen area. Malaysia appears under the "List of third countries whose nationals are exempted from holding a visa when crossing the external borders", **so as a Malaysian citizen you do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area.**

When you arrive in the Schengen area (it sounds like this is Geneva, although maybe you have some other connection) you'll have to show the border guard your passport, probably answer a few questions about the purpose of your trip, and then receive an entry stamp.

There are typically no border checks when you travel between countries within the Schengen area, though occasional spot-checks are possible. This is nothing to worry about if it happens, just show them your passport with the entry stamp.

Comment: I see. As this is my first time travelling to europe, may I know where can I apply visa? Can it be done in embassy?

Comment: @Idonknow yes, French visa applications in Malaysia are processed by the embassy in Kuala Lumpur. All the information you need should be [here](https://my.ambafrance.org/applying-french-visa-in-malaysia).

Comment: Actually i am a Malaysian residing in Singapore. So I can just apply French visa in embassy Singapore?

Comment: @Idonknow most countries prefer you to apply from the country where you live, so most likely yes. If you have more questions about *how/where* you need to apply for a French visa, I'd suggest opening a new question as it's not something I'm an expert on, and a new question would get more attention than these comments.

Comment: @Idonknow AFAIK you should apply via  https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/sg

Comment: However https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjDtqSK8KThAhVimuYKHYLCB6kQzPwBegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.etiaseurope.eu%2Fetias-requirements%2Fmalaysian%2Ffrance%2F&psig=AOvVaw1ynj-Y5VgAYL-9sVjSnBPD&ust=1553863855351992&cshid=1553777452224 states that Malaysians do not need a visa to visit France for short stay less than 90 days.

Comment: @Idonknow you're right. I must have missed Malaysia somehow when I checked the list of visa exempt countries. As a Malaysian citizen, you won't need a visa. I'll edit this answer to correct it.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the effort to check it.

Comment: @Idonknow Here is the official site for reference https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf